# Hidden inputs in formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic

I'm trying to add a hidden input with a predetermined "value" in it

```
<%= f.input :step, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "3" } %>
```

In this instance I'm using hidden inputs to determined which form on a page with more than one form is submitted.

This looks to display correctly in the html but submitting the form produces this error

> unknown attribute: step

Comment: Do you have a step field on your model?

Comment: no I don't, it's just for the controller to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the field isn't on your model you have to choices. You can simply use the [hidden_field_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag) like in the following:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'step' %>
```

Or you can add a virtual attribute to your model and use the code you've shown. Like in the following:

```
class Model

  attr_accessor :step

end
```

I can't say which I would use because I don't what you're trying to do with the step field.

Comment: If the user submitted the form with "step 1" then i want to controller to redirect_to using :anchor as "step 2" for example.

Comment: So you should choose the first option ;) You can access the step in the controller with `params[:step]`